# Javascript index of array is array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I do not understand Javascript interpretation of the next lines of code:

```js
var a = ["value"];
console.log(a[0]); // value
console.log(a[[0]]); // value
console.log(a[[[0]]]); // value
//...
```

Why is an array taken as the value 0?

Comment: [0].toString() is "0".  a["0"] === "value"

Comment: @user120242 And the explanation for the implicit `.toString()`?

Comment: `a[~~![]] === a[+[]]`

Comment: I am not a Developer of ECMA-Script but I'd say that they built in a feature to ignore unnecessary dimensions. In your case it is obvious that the 2 outer brackets are of no need or use and so JavaScript still only performs "console.log(a[0])". Just an opinion.

Comment: @Lynx242, no that is not the reason for this behaviour.

Comment: Arrays are exotic objects with special treatment for an array index.  If the input property is not an array index (representable integer), and since arrays are still objects, it cascades to normal object access, which after implicitly casting to a string to fit property names which can either be string or Symbol, cascades back to integer/array index access.  There's a bunch of relevant specs at [ECMA-262 specs](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-property-accessors-runtime-semantics-evaluation).  I don't know if this justifies attempting a full write up?

Comment: Most likely for optimization (see V8 packed optimizations) and semantics of strings and integers, and of Arrays as (exotic) objects, and historical reasons influenced by the former.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bracket notation is used as property accessor, and is defined in the [ECMAScript Language Specification](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/11.0/index.html#sec-property-accessors), under chapter "Property Accessors". The expression between square brackets is processed in step 4 as:

> EvaluatePropertyAccessWithExpressionKey(baseValue, Expression, strict).

...which in turn performs the following step:

> ToPropertyKey(propertyNameValue).

...[which](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/11.0/index.html#sec-topropertykey) in turn performs this step:

> ToPrimitive(argument, hint String).

...which, if you drill down further in the specification will convert that expression to string if it is an object, using either the `Symbol.toPrimitive` (if it's defined) or the `toString` method. And yes, if the expression between the outermost brackets is an array (maybe nested), like [0], or [[0]], ...etc, you pass an object.

An array converted to string (with its `toString()` method) will produce a comma separated string of its values. This works recursively into nested arrays, so this practically means that all values, no matter how deeply nested, come out in the resulting comma separated string. For example `[[1, 2], 3, [4, [5]]].toString()` is "1,2,3,4,5".

In your examples, there is always just one value, 0, in the array that you pass as expression to the outer bracket pair. So that expression, such as `[[[[[0]]]]].toString()`, resolves to "0".

And so we get `a["0"]`, which is the same thing as `a[0]`.

Comment: why a["0"] === a[0] ? does it covert "0" to 0 when trying to access the property ?

Comment: @zb22 https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-integerindexedelementget  look at integer index and array index definition and "CanonicalNumericIndexString"

Comment: @zb22 https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-integer-indexed-exotic-objects-get-p-receiver pasted wrong hash, this is the one you'd want to look at